# Getting Extra Data Based on Original SQL Result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a page that shows the top 10 users and how many articles those top 10 users have total, how many articles that user has over the last 30 days, 90 days and 180 days.

The top 10 users are retrieved based on total articles and this should be the default sort. For the 30, 90 and 180 day stats they should be for these same 10 users.

What I don't know how to do is get all of this information for these ten users, sort by total and then show the rest as well.

There is nothing in the database that has the 30, 90 and 180 days stored so they will have to be calculated based on date range.

There is a user table and an article table with a relation of userid and the article table has a date that each article was created.

The query would find the top 10 users based on total articles and then calculate the 30, 90 and 180 articles created during that time frame. I would then be able to present that in an html table.

Thanks.

Edit: An example of how the data will be presented: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nce5w.png

Comment: do you have a sqlfiddle for this scenario?

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` with a subquery to add the table again for the 30, 90, and 180 counts.

Comment: Here is an example of how it will look http://i.imgur.com/BjALeHZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This single query selects the top 10 users within an inline view (`top_10_users`), and for these users, the number of articles are counted using the CASE statement. If the date difference falls within a specific range, then 1 is added to the SUM, thus getting the count of records in that date range.

```
select
    u.user_name User,
    count(*) Total_Posts, 
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), created_date) < 31 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) Posts_Last_30_days,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), created_date) BETWEEN 31 AND 90 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) Posts_Last_90_days,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), created_date) BETWEEN 91 AND 180 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) Posts_Last_180_days
from 
(
    select user_id, count(article_id) cnt_articles
    from user_articles
    group by user_id
    order by count(article_id) desc
    limit 10  
) top_10_users 
inner join user_articles ua on top_10_users.user_id = ua.user_id
inner join users u on ua.user_id = u.user_id
group by u.user_name
order by count(*);
```

[<kbd>SQL Fiddle demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8aa7d/20)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this Many to Many relationship table `user_articles` contain the following column `(userid, articleid)`.

And your article table might contain a `date_issued date datatype` column.

To access user top 10 for the day.

```
Select count(ua.articleid), ua.userid 
from user_articles ua, articleid a
where  ua.articleid = a.articleid
group by ua.userid, a.date_issued
order by 1
limit 10;
```

To get the user's total of article for the last 30 days

```
select sum(article_count), userid
from (Select count(ua.articleid) as article_count, ua.userid, a.date_issued 
      from user_articles ua, articleid a
      where  ua.articleid = a.articleid    
      group by ua.userid, a.date_issued
      order by 1
      limit 10)
where date_issued between curdate()-30 and curdate()
group by userid;
```

To get the user's total user article for the last 90 days just change

```
where date_issued between curdate()-30 and curdate()
```

to

```
where date_issued between curdate()-90 and curdate()
```

Same you will do for 180 days.